# networking with one NIC and access to internet and virtual machines

Tags: networking, bridge, nic

I have installed opennebula and I have followed [this](http://opennebula.org/documentation:archives:rel3.4:vmg) tutorial.
Unfortunately I cannot ssh to the virtual machines that appear to be in a running state and already have an IP.
The problem might be that I have one NIC and although I read that I should use bridging I am not sure if this is possible and how.

brctl show command output is

```
bridge name    bridge id            STP enabled    interfaces
br0            8000.50e549b5e2aa    no             eth0
                                                   vnet0
virbr0         8000.000000000000    yes
```

vnet0 is the interface of the VM. If I construct a VM to use the virtual bridge virbr0 I have the same problem.

my interfaces file is

```
iface br0 inet static
address X.X.X.172
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway X.X.X.200
pre-up ifconfig eth0 down
pre-up brctl addbr br0
pre-up brctl addif br0 eth0
pre-up ifconfig eth0 up
post-down ifconfig eth0 down
post-down brctl delif br0 eth0

iface eth0 inet manual
```

In ifconfig br0 has been assigned the IP defined in interfaces (which is public) while vnet0 appears to send data (TX bytes > 0) but never receive (RX bytes = 0).
Am I missing something? Is it possible to ssh to a VM having one NIC or I need to have a second one?

Answer (score 0):

What OpenNebula assumes in its documentation [here](http://opennebula.org/documentation:archives:rel3.4:vgg) is that the hosts use two physical interfaces one for private network and one for internet connectivity. Of course if a host has only one interface it can connect to only one of the networks.
The solution I tried so that do not lose internet connectivity was to change interfaces file so that the br0 interface is automatically assigned IP by DHCP

```
iface br0 inet dhcp
```

I also changed network definition file so that it contains leases of public IP addresses that were not assigned by dhcp. The virtual machine I instantiated was successfully assigned a public IP. Although I was able to ssh to that virtual machine then so can anybody on the internet so I am not going to keep this configuration.